# Shipping methods are still showing even disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I am working on [Depoto](https://www.depoto.com/) website.

In this, I have disabled all shipping methods in admin panel but still those all available shipping methods are showing on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using multi store environment be sure that you have selected the correct store from the store drop down before disabling that particular shipping.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared the issue.
Issue is:

The entire shipping methods settings were modified. Strange, Why it happened we don't know. After I figured out, I have checked and modified the entire settings for Default, Website and store-views. Now, The issue was cleared.

Comment: I am also facing this type of issue.  Thanks for explanation. We will check it.